# JQuery: Adding space between multiple selections

Tags: jquery

I select some paragraphs inside a div:

```
$('#myDiv p.p1, #myDiv p.p2').text();
```

My problem is that I want to add space between each selection so that the output is: "paragraph1 (space) paragraph2" instead of "paragraph1paragraph2".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `.map()` with `.get()` to create an array of the separate paragraphs, then use `.join(" ")` to join them together with a space in between.

Try this:

```
var result = $('#myDiv p.p1, #myDiv p.p2').map(function() {
    return $.text([this]);
    // return this.innerHTML;              // Alternate means of getting text
    // return this.firstChild.nodeValue;   // Another alternate
}).get().join(" ");
```

The `result` variable should have your paragraphs with a space separating them.

- http://api.jquery.com/map/
- http://api.jquery.com/get/
- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp

**EDIT:** Based on comment from **@J-P**, updated the text retrieval to be more efficient.

Comment: +1, although I think `$.text([this])` will be a bit faster than constructing a new jQ object with `$(this)`...

Answer (score -1):

This will do the trick:

```
$('#myDiv p.p1, #myDiv p.p2').clone().append(' ').text()
```

Comment: What is wrong with this solution since someone voted it down? Its much simpler then patricks.

Comment: Gert - While I didn't down vote you (I don't like to do that against competing answers), I imagine it is because you are making unnecessary DOM modifications, and DOM modifications are slow.

Comment: @Thariama, @Gert - Just did a quick test (in Firefox only) comparing the two in a loop of 1000 iterations. DOM modification took around 2,200 ms, mine took around 100 ms. Avoid the DOM when you can. :o)

Comment: @patrick - I appreciate your feedback. I guess `$('#myDiv p.p1, #myDiv p.p2').clone().append(' ').text()` would have been better. Not sure how speedy the `clone()` function is though.

Comment: Gert - Using `.clone()` provided a massive improvement. Brought it down to around 190 ms! Still not quite as fast, but *much* better.

Comment: @patrick - Yes, you're right. Shorter code isn't always better or faster... :D Thanks again for the feedback.